# https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml” blocked in my company

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml  is blocked in my company. so "android SDK manager" not retrieving all packages. how to get the packages without unblocking the above LINK

Comment: Consult the network team  of your company and ask them to allow access to it or try downloading it using a modem or worst case download the archives at home and paste it into your workstation (provided flash drives are allowed).

Comment: What archieves need to be download and from where to get it?

Comment: Download SDK updates on the computer which has the google repository access then zip and copy the android sdk folder. Going this way, again there will be problem downloading project dependencies. Better ask your company to allow access to google repository, jcenter, Maven Central, etc.